# Node http request under IIS Node failing against Azure CORS webservice - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, cors, iisnode

When running purely under node everything works perfectly, as soon as I try to run under IIS Node, the Node http request fails every time with ENOTFOUND on getaddrinfo.  This is part of a mid sized website with everything else working under Node and IIS Node, just this request to an Azure CORS web service is failing.  I also have similar web service requests to google maps that work perfectly in both environments.  Both the google maps and the Azure web service calls use the same shared code to handle the request.

```
// Simplified
//==================================
var http = require("http")

var options = {
  host: "xxx.azurewebsites.net",
  path: "/address?postcode=SL6+1PB",
  headers: {
    "SerialNo": "xxx",
    "RegKey": "xxx",
    "Company": "xxx"
  }
};

req = https.request(options, callback);
req.end();


// The Whole thing
//===========================
function getData(host, port, path, headers, data, secure) {
    return new promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var options = {}, req;

        try {
            options.host = host;
            if(!!port) {options.port = port;}
            if(!!data) {options.method = "POST";}
            if(!!path) {options.path = path.replace(/\s+/g, "+");}
            if(!!headers) {options.headers = headers;}

            if(!!secure) {req = https.request(options, callback);}
            else {req = http.request(options, callback);}

            req.on("error", function(error) {
                rejectPromise(reject, error, "datahttp.getData");
            });

            if(!!data) {req.write((typeof(data) === "object" ? JSON.stringify(data) : data));}
            req.end();
        }
        catch(error) {
            // This error object drops the message property on stringify
            error = {method: "datahttp.getData", success: false, message: error.message};
            rejectPromise(reject, error, "datahttp.getData");
        }

        function callback(response) {
            var str = "";

            //another chunk of data has been received, so append it to `str`
            response.on("data", function(chunk) {
                str += String(chunk);
            });

            // the whole response has been received
            response.on("end", function () {
                if(response.statusCode == 200) {
                    try {
                        switch(response.headers["content-type"].split(";")[0]) {
                            case "application/xml":
                                xmlToJSN(str)
                                    .then(function(result) {
                                        resolve({method: "datahttp.getData", success: true, data: result});
                                    })
                                    .catch(function(error) {
                                        rejectPromise(reject, error, "datahttp.getData");
                                    });

                                break;

                            case "application/json":
                                resolve({method: "datahttp.getData", success: true, data: JSON.parse(str)});
                                break;

                            default:
                                resolve({method: "datahttp.getData", success: true, data: str});
                        }
                    }
                    catch(error) {
                        rejectPromise(reject, error, "datahttp.getData");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    rejectPromise(reject, {message: response.statusMessage + " (" + response.statusCode + ")"}, "datahttp.getData");
                }
            });

            response.on("error", function(error) {
                rejectPromise(reject, error, "datahttp.getData");
            });
        }

    });
}
```

I have been struggling with this for a few days and clearly just not seeing something very obvious, some help and a smack upside the head would be welcome

```
Stack Trace
====================
Trace: { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND daaddressing-prod-ne.azurewebsites.net/ daaddressing-prod-ne.azurewebsites.net/:80]
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'daaddressing-prod-ne.azurewebsites.net/',
  host: 'daaddressing-prod-ne.azurewebsites.net/',
  port: 80 }
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\Node\acinet_flint\server\datahttp.js:47:29)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:269:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:1012:8)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND daaddressing-prod-ne.azurewebsites.net/ daaddressing-prod-ne.azurewebsites.net/:80]
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'daaddressing-prod-ne.azurewebsites.net/',
  host: 'daaddressing-prod-ne.azurewebsites.net/',
  port: 80,
  service: 'acinet',
  success: false,
  method: 'datahttp.getData' }
```

Comment: Could we have a stack trace to go with that error?

Comment: At this right moment, daaddressing-prod-ne.azurewebsites.net/ gives a 404 error

Comment: I tested with your code snippet: `req = http.request(options, callback);` against your server which is `daaddressing-prod-ne.azurewebsites.net/address?postcode=SL6+1PB`, it worked fine on my side on Azure Web Apps in IISNode env. Could you provide more details about your client env?

Comment: Ok I finally found the problem and its a very silly one... Using the host string "daaddressing-prod-ne.azurewebsites.net/" works perfectly under node but fails under IIS Node, simply removing '/' from the end of the host and its works in both environments, why this is the case bamboozles the hell out of me.

Comment: Seems a trailing slash doesn't work under pure Node either the problem was my config, IIS Node config had the trailing slash but under pure Node I didn't, I must have compared those values a hundred times and missed it.  Thanks for trying to help and my apologizes for missing something so simple